# jQuery - css("background-image", variable) doesn't work :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to save the background-image of a element, remove it and then maybe add it back later.

```
var current_bg_image = $("#div").css("background-image");
if(something){
  $("#div").css("background-image", "none");
}else{
  $("#div").css("background-image", current_bg_image); // not working...
}
```

The part where the background image is supposed to be added back doesn't work...
But if I change `current_bg_image` with `"url(something.jpg)"` it works. It seems that css() doesn't work with variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine for me using jQuery 1.5.1. I believe what you will get once saving the background-image value to `current_bg_image` is the full path to the image, so try reading that value using Firebug or `alert(current_bg_image)` and ensure it is what you think it should be.

Comment: tx, actually the problem was that `var current_bg_image = $("#div").css("background-image");` was running everytime the function was called, I put it outside and now its ok :)

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem, solved by this:

`var id = $(this).attr("src");
//alert(id);
$('#div').css({'background-image': 'url(' + id + ')',
});`